# Monitoring IBSS (ad hoc) networks

Tags: router, lan

I have router enabling fixed MAC's to connect to internet. All devices are connected by LAN to the router. Problem I'm having is that i don't want to allow another device connect through one using ad hoc network with allowed internet sharing. Is there a way to monitor this? and Can I identify whether there was more than one device connected through 1 MAC from router logs? 
(I have access only to the router).
Edit: ad hoc is NAT

Thanks.

Comment: Router is Cisco 7301. And ok I edit question to be correct.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Most likely, the device doing the sharing is acting as a router.  That is, the ad-hoc network will be one subnet and the LAN connection another.  In that case, the MAC address of the packets will always be the sharing PC.  Depending on the way the sharing PC is set up, it may also be performing NAT, so the source IP address also will be that of the PC.  That will make it difficult to tell the difference.

If the sharing PC acts as a bridge, then you will see the original MAC addresses, and you can filter on that.

Comment: I'm asking exclusively about NAT, tested bridge earlier and it showed original MAC (as you are saying). From tests with NAT I can not see difference, so it is possible it can not be detected.

Comment: With NAT, there will be nothing in the router logs.

Comment: There is not. I meant I can not see difference between ad hoc device connected and not connected.